# How to add navigators (left & right) on Horizontal <s:List> in Flex Spark

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

My question is about List in Flex Spark (in Flash Builder). 
I was referring to [Flex Horizontal List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691374/flex-horizontal-list) to create my Horizontal List using -

```
<s:List id="myList">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

I now want to add navigators ('<' & '>') on the sides on this Horizontal list upon clicking which list should scroll from left to right or vice versa. I have just started with Flex and not sure how I can achieve this. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just define a width on the List, and it will include scroll bars automatically:

```
<s:List id="myList" width="200">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Comment: Thanks! This brings the default 'HTML-style' slider. I am looking to add actual buttons PREVIOUS & FORWARD, that can scroll through the list items.